# How can I use SMB shares under Mavericks?

Tags: network, macos, smb

There seem to be different problems and solutions to this problem floating around:

1. [Fix switching from SMB to cifs](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/10/27/did-mavericks-kill-your-network-drive-access-heres-a-fix/)
2. [Not being able to access OS X shares from Windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107544/since-upgrading-to-os-x-mavericks-i-cant-open-any-files-on-a-smb-share-from-my)
3. [All kinds of problems with SMB and Mavericks over at Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5467191)

My problem is like in the first link: I have a Raspberry Pi (Linux) SMB server. It serves files to my MBP running Mavericks. However, I cannot connect to the Pi. The Console logging says:

```
30.10.13 21:50:53,422 NetAuthSysAgent[6632]: smb_mount: mount failed to raspberrypi/MyShare, syserr = File exists
```

When I go to `/Volumes` in a shell and do an `ls`, I get this:

```
user@mac:/Volumes $ ls -l
ls: MyShare: Invalid argument
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  1 28 Okt 21:39 M4 -> /
user@mac:/Volumes $
```

So my main hard drive M4 is visible, the share produces an invalid argument. I already rebooted my Mac three times.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason you are using SMB over AFP on your RPi?

Comment: Yes, I also have Windows machines on my network. :)

Comment: Would you consider using SMB on Windows and AFP on Mac? :)

Comment: Oh well... Maybe I'll try it, just because I never used AFP! However, after the fourth reboot everything works -- for now! I'll keep an eye on this problem, and will try to formulate a useful answer.

Comment: Yup, I just set up AFP, and it works great. Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: Done! :) I've added some more information about setting up Netatalk in case anyone else finds this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't get SMB working, try AFP. You can run both side-by-side, and use SMB on your Windows and AFP on OS X.

---

To set up AFP on your Raspberry Pi, you can use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install netatalk
```

This will install Netatalk on your RPi, and following successful installation, the RPi should automatically show in the Shared section in Finder and the Network neighbourhood (⌘⇧K):

[image]

<sup>If not, you can connect manually by pressing ⌘K and typing `afp://` followed by the IP address of your RPi.</sup>

Comment: After a month of usage, I can say this works fine. But it seems actually best to name the AFP server differently than the SMB server. I changed the netbios name in smb.conf, but you could also change the name in netatalk's afp_signature.conf.

Answer (score 0):

This post solved my problem. Try manually setting the maximum transmission unit under your system settings>Networks>WLAN/Ethernet>Advanced>Hardware>Custom MTU of 1320.

My Problem was also a mounting delay problem. Once I got things mounted, everything worked normally. Apparently, the default MTU is too high. Manually lowering this made mounting smb shares a much faster process.

The original post I will paste here for the sake of keeping stackexchange self-contained:

> I have embarked on a testing mission... Using Wireshark I managed to
>   see that packets were being dropped when transferring over the network
>   - the same patterns didn't exist with the same transfer over wireless or the same transfer wired to a Windows server.
>
> So I Googled a little and came up with the following command:
>
> ping -c 1 -D -s 1500 smbserver
>
> It basically pings the server with an MTU of 1500, to which I got:
>
> ping: sendto: Message too long
>
> Note that I also get this error on a Windows server - but what may be
>   the issue is that when your software gets this response it is supposed
>   to automatically decrease the MTU until it finds the optimal one for
>   transfer of packets - something that Mavericks appears to be doing
>   with Windows servers but not with Linux ones.
>
> So using the ping command I can find an optimal MTU for transfer:
>
> ping -c 1 -D -s 1320 smbserver
>
> Now I get the answer:
>
> round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.829/0.829/0.829/0.000 ms
>
> I had to mess around trying to find the optimal level but it gives you
>   an idea on the test.  After this I take my number and go to:
>
> System Preferences -> Network -> USB Ethernet -> Advanced... ->
>   Hardware -> Configure: Manually -> MTU Custom: 1320
>
> After this, I disconnected my shares, re-established them and then
>   tried another transfer up to my Linux server.  Success! Granted it's
>   not what I'd deem to be full speed, but to get a 5GB transfer down
>   from 8 hours to 30 minutes seems better.   It has taken it from
>   completely unusable to tolerable.
>
> I'm not entirely sure what the root of the problem is as I'm not a
>   networking expert, as the stepping back of MTU appears to work on a
>   Windows server and not a Linux one, and it worked fine in previous
>   versions of OS X, my guess is that it is driver and/or stack related.
>
> BTW I tried updating to 10.9.1 via the Developer download before
>   trying this, the 10.9.1 upgrade didn't fix the issue for me before I
>   went troubleshooting.